# Monitor directory for regular file creation and alert if the stream of files stops

Tags: remote, raspbian-stretch, headless, monitoring, file

I have had a Raspberry Pi Zero W controlled, time-lapse camera taking pictures, of a construction project, every 60 seconds for nearly three months and recently it's started failing.  I suspect the issue lies in the camera hard or software (CHDKPTP), not the Pi.  So I need the Pi to tell me when it happens.

The system is running Rasbian Stretch.

Image are uploaded immediately to my web hosting and added to a web gallery, so to check that the system it's working I have to either use an FTP program, or look at the gallery page. This is inconvenient and I sometimes find I've missed several hours of images when the camera has crashed.

So I am looking for unix tool to keep an eye on the uploads and alert me by email, or even better, SMS, a few minutes after the files stop arriving - during the daily capture period, of 7:30am - 4:30pm.

[inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) looks promising but I can't find reference to alert on 'failed but expected' file creation events, only alerting on 'new' file creation events.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct about `ifnotify` - and kudos to you for discovering it.  It cannot react to the absence of an event.

What you are going to want is a script or a python program to do as you described.

Either can monitor a directory to see if it has had a file added.

It is not clear to me whether your stream of files means that every XX seconds a NEW file is added.

If so, it is trivial to do a script that is regularly run as a `cron` script that does a `ls -al | wc >./tmp.tmp` then some logic to determine whether the length of `./tmp.tmp` is getting longer.

Python works much the same.  You would `import os` then use `os.listdir('.')` to get the list of the current directory. I would save the directory as a file, then each time use this to both compare with the file and to then save it for next time.

Note that the most frequently that `cron` can launch a job is down to the minute.

Using `cron` is much more efficient than leaving a program running all the time comparing the clock, unless (for example) you use a `sleep 1` command in a script to release the processor for a second each loop.

---

As for getting the alerts, see this Q&A:

[Simplest way to send one-line mail out via command line using gmail?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363814/simplest-way-to-send-one-line-mail-out-via-command-line-using-gmail)

It can send SMS if you know the `mailto:` link to your phone.

Each carrier has a different method, similar to this:

```
19074561234@.txt.att.com
```

You will need to look that part up and just use it as your target email address as described in the link above.

Comment: thanks heaps for both the encouragement and the links. I have scripted gmail emails before but I am surprised how simple it seems to extend that to SMS.
I am, however having some difficulty determining the mailto address of my service, which is Amaysim here in Australia.
I did find a Gmail addon which works to send email to text and the mailto address in the sent archive appears too be:
+61XXXXXXXXXX@mmsc.optus.com.au

Comment: ..however that address fails when I try to use it in either ssmtp or mailx 
with this error:
***Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822;+61XXXXXXXXXX@mmsc.optus.com.au
Status: 5.0.0***

Comment: It is sometimes difficult finding the SMS address.  For me, it is pretty simple since I set up Google Voice.  All I have to do is send a text to my Google Voice number, and I have it set up to also forward to email.  That way, in both places you can see the originating mailto: address for the text messages.